# Why does unplugging my laptop trigger a 'lid close' event?

Tags: 11.04, laptop, gnome-power-manager, aspire-one

Ever since switching my Acer Aspire One D150 laptop over to 11.04 full-time, I've noticed that whenever I remove the AC adapter plug from the computer it goes into standby immediately. This happens regardless of how long it's been charging.  Some quick searching yielded [this Launchpad report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/601709), but it's been closed for some time with no solution posted.  I've got a simple workaround by setting the 'lid close' event in the power manager to simply turn the screen off. Is there a known fix for this or should I open a new issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar - if not more pertinent - [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/364592) for your laptop model.

Reading through the bug report, it appears that the BIOS on your laptop is a good candidate for further investigation.

The bug report mentions version 1.09a of the BIOS that fixes the issue.  Can I suggest you look for the latest BIOS update from your vendor website.

Comment: I updated my BIOS to v1.13 from 1.05 and it's fixed :D. Thanks!